# Is using std::optional<int> as efficient as using int?

Tags: c++, performance, option-type, c++14, boost-optional

I have a quad-/octree data structure. Im storing the children indexes/ptrs of a cell in an array. Each position in the array represents the location of a child with respect to its parent, e.g. in 2D:

```
// _____________
// |     |     |
// |  2  |  3  |
// |_____|_____|
// |     |     |
// |  0  |  1  |
// |_____|_____|
// for each cell, 4 children are always stored in row-major order
std::vector<std::array<Integer,4>> children;
```

I know that the max number of children is a subset of the values that an `Integer` type can represent. Thus I can identify if a cell is missing a child by using a ''magic'' value like `-1` for `Integer = int`, or `std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max()` for `Integer = unsigned`. This is something that `std::optional<Integer>` cannot assume.

As far as I understood, this usage of magic values is one of the raison d'être of `std::optional`. Still, I'm worried about the performance of `std::vector<std::optional<int>>` in inner loops.

So,

- Will the performance of `std::vector<std::optional<int>>` be worse than that of `std::vector<int>`? (I'm already doing the comparison for "non-existent" value).
- Or, can the implementation of `std::optional` be optimized to offer the same performance as a raw `int`? And how?

Mixing `std::optional` in the return type of my functions and magic values in my data structure sounds like a very bad idea. I prefer to be consistent and either use one or the other (at least within the same context). Although I could overload the function that performs the comparison with the magic number:

```
template<T> bool is_valid(const T& t) { 
  return /* comparison with magic value for t */; 
}
```

for optional types.

Comment: Not sure about the performace between the two, that's something you'd have to see for you self. Question though, is using bit-information viable solution for you? Since you are storing indexes, can you encode information about the 4 child indeces in a single int? Since you have 4 children, you can use 4 bytes(or more) for each children, that makes 16 bytes total for indeces, and the other 16 you can use to encode whether its active or not? Make a class to handle this so user wouldn't have to worry about internals

Comment: The raison d'être of `std::optional`, is precisely cases where you *don't* have a sentinel value.  If you have an "obvious" sentinel, why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: @user814628 Each index is an unsigned long long... I have a lot of cells and cannot do what you propose.

Comment: @AndréCaron: It would make for clearer code (more cleary expressing the intent). Indeed, it would be nice if you could declare a sentinel value for user-defined types and tell `optional` to use that. You could even make construction of that sentinel value private with `std::optional<yourtype>` as friend.

Comment: If you use `vector<compact_optional<int>>` you get both type-safety and zero-performance overhead. Try: https://github.com/akrzemi1/compact_optional

Comment: @Andrzej github.com/gnzlbg/ndtree uses a modified version of your `compact_optional` library extensively for this ;) Thanks :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`std::optional` is going to require additional storage and fit fewer values into cache (it appears you already know the reason for this).

I don't think it's wrong to have a different value stored internally in your data structure from the one exposed by the public API, as long as the internal representation is completely hidden from users.

Furthermore, I suggest you isolate the magic number into a single pair of `inline` conversion functions.

The compiler should help you remember to use the conversion functions consistently, by generating type errors if you forget.  You might even use a thin struct wrapper for an `int` in your internal data structure, to ensure that no implicit conversion exists (or define a user-defined conversion).

```
class CompressedOptionalUInt
{
    static const unsigned SENTINEL_MISSING = std::numeric_limits<unsigned>::max();
    unsigned value;

public:
    CompressedOptionalUInt(std::optional<unsigned> val) : value(!val? SENTINEL_MISSING: *val) {}
    operator std::optional<unsigned>() const { ... }
};
```

and then use `std::array<CompressedOptionalUInt>`.

Making that into a template, with just the sentinel needing to be defined for each type, should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! Using a thin struct wrapper sounds like a great idea!

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not as efficient. As you can see from the [reference implementation](https://github.com/akrzemi1/Optional/blob/master/optional.hpp) it has to store, update and check an extra value.